# classification_report using confusion matrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science

We have a confusion matrix for my ML model.

```
array([[508,  12],
       [ 78,  36]])
```

We also have `classification_report`

```
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.83      0.98      0.90       123
           1       0.85      0.31      0.45        36

    accuracy                           0.83       159
   macro avg       0.84      0.64      0.67       159
weighted avg       0.83      0.83      0.80       159
```

To understand the efficacy of this ML solution, we have a confusion matrix generated for traditionally built system

```
array([[305,  62],
       [ 108,  50]])
```

Is there a way to generate `classification_report` from this? Standard function rather than coding, to ensure consistency.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read this post here https://towardsdatascience.com/beyond-accuracy-precision-and-recall-3da06bea9f6c . From the values in your confusion matrix, you can calculate the true positives, true negatives, false positives and false negatives. Afterwards, you can calculate any metrics which use them.

I found one code example ([source](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/87183/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix))

```
def evaluate(self, dataset):
        predictions = self.predict(dataset[:,0])
        confusion_matrix = sklearn_confusion_matrix(dataset[:,1], predictions, labels=self.__classes)

        precisions = []
        recalls = []
        accuracies = []

        for gender in self.__classes:
            idx = self.__classes_indexes[gender]
            precision = 1
            recall = 1
            if np.sum(confusion_matrix[idx,:]) > 0:
                precision = confusion_matrix[idx][idx]/np.sum(confusion_matrix[idx,:])
            if np.sum(confusion_matrix[:, idx]) > 0:
                recall = confusion_matrix[idx][idx]/np.sum(confusion_matrix[:, idx])
            precisions.append(precision)
            recalls.append(recall)

        precision = np.mean(precisions)
        recall = np.mean(recalls)
        f1 = (2*(precision*recall))/float(precision+recall)
        accuracy = np.sum(confusion_matrix.diagonal())/float(np.sum(confusion_matrix))

        return precision, recall, accuracy, f1
```

In the code you can see how the confusion matrix can be created and the scores can be derived. I know that you already have the matrix, so maybe you can just take a look at the second part and try to understand how the scores are calculated using the matrix only.